# Use a modified notary client for docker trust command

Tags: docker, hsm, notary

I am trying to set up docker so that it works with a modified version of notary, that pulls the private keys from my HSM.

For this I am using this fork from notary:
https://github.com/gemalto/notary

The notary command is working, I can sign files without a problem and the private keys are stored in my HSM.
I can't seem to be able to make docker use my modified notary though.
Is there a way to for example change some bin files or modify a config file to get my desired effect?

What I am trying to do is to modify the command `docker trust sign` such that it uses my modified notary and pulls the root-key from the HSM.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to build [Docker CLI](https://github.com/docker/cli) with  https://github.com/gemalto/notary :

> When you run a docker pull command, Docker Engine is using an
>   integrated Notary library (the same one as Notary CLI)

Taken from https://docs.docker.com/notary/getting_started/